# How to run a jar file along with its multiple external properties files using a .bat file?

Tags: java, maven, batch-file, jar

I have a Maven project with three properties files under resources directory.

Existing scenario:

- At the moment, I create jar file in Eclipse through maven build with goal as "assembly:single" ensuring that the build tag in pom.xml is updated appropriately.
- This gives me a jar file with all the dependencies embedded in it.
- I execute this jar file with dependencies using batch command `java -jar myjarname.jar`

Desired scenario:

- However, I would like to export my project as a jar file without dependencies using "Export" feature of eclipse and place the three properties files in the same directory as where the jar file resides.

What should be the command to pass my properties files as arguments to the `java -jar myname.jar` ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to prepare your program using runtime argument pass facility like below

```
public class Echo {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
      //  args[0] is argument1
       // args[1] is argument2
    }
}
```

and then update your batch file like below

```
java -jar myjarname.jar argument1 argument2
```

you can see more example:

```
class A{  
public static void main(String args[]){  

for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++)  
System.out.println(args[i]);  

}  
}
```

execution command:

> compile by > javac A.java
>   run by > java A sonoo jaiswal 1 3 abc

```
Output: sonoo
       jaiswal
       1
       3
       abc
```